# Reading all the namespaces in a DOM document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to read all the namespaces in a DOM document.

My input XML file is:

```
<a:Sample xmlns:a="http://a.org/" 
    xmlns:b="http://b.org/">
    <a:Element b:Attribute="text"> </a:Element>
</a:Sample>
```

I want to get all the prefixes with their associated namespaces in the given input XML.

I have a method with the following definition.

```
public Document check(Document srcfile) {
    Document naReport = null;

    if(srcfile != null) {
        // Parse the document using builder.
        if (srcfile instanceof DocumentTraversal) {
            DocumentTraversal dt = (DocumentTraversal) srcfile;
            NodeIterator i = dt.createNodeIterator(srcfile, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false);
            System.out.println(srcfile.getPrefix());
            System.out.println(srcfile.getNamespaceURI());
            Element element = (Element) i.nextNode();
            while (element != null) {
                String prefix = element.getPrefix();
                if (prefix != null) {
                    String uri = element.getNamespaceURI();
                    System.out.println("Prefix: " + prefix);
                    System.out.println("URI: " + uri);
                    // bindings.put(prefix, uri);
                }
                element = (Element) i.nextNode();
            }
        }
    }

    return naReport; 
}
```

But, when I run my program, I'm getting the following output:

```
Prefix: a
URI: http://a.org/
Prefix: a
URI: http://a.org/
```

Could someone help me.

Comment: You are only looking at the namespace of the element.  The b namespace is only used on the element's attributes.  You will have to examine all the attributes too and collect the namespaces from them.

Comment: I have changed the node iterator to have both elements and attributes as follows:
 NodeIterator i = dt.createNodeIterator(srcfile, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT | NodeFilter.SHOW_ATTRIBUTE, null, false);

Even then I'm getting the same result.

Comment: That won't work.  SHOW_ATTRIBUTE is not terribly useful.   See the comment in the Javadoc for createNodeIterator.  "Since attributes are never children of other nodes, they do not appear when traversing over the document tree."   You'll have to loop over the attributes on each element separately for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop over the attributes of each element inside your main element loop:

```
NamedNodeMap map = element.getAttributes();
for (int iattr=0; iattr<map.getLength(); iattr++) {
   Attr attr = (Attr)map.item(iattr);
   if (attr.getNamespaceURI() != null) {
      System.out.println("Attr " + attr.getName() + " -  " + attr.getNamespaceURI());
   }
}
```

Comment: There is one more problem I'm struggling with.
I want a Map of scope and list of namespace objects(a namespace object will have both prefix and namespace url). Is it possible to get it?